# SNMP4j vs JMX? what to choose for myapplication

Tags: java, jmx, snmp, snmp4j

Regarding applications administration, I think SNMP4j and JMX are the most used standards. Looking to the documentation of each one, I got confused and not able to choose one or the other. So, I decided to get post and get some feedback from people who already have experience with the topic. 
What I want to do is to consult and change the configuration of some elements and also get some statistics.. I would consider the efficiency, easiness of use and availability of documentation..
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can go for JMX. As the documentation for JMX is good enough to create a JMX interface for you application but on the other side SNMP4J is lagging with respect to the documentation. If you have any doubt please let me know.
Regards,
Raghav

Comment: Thanks Raghav. I indeed went for JMX for the same reason (documentation)... and it seems to work fine :)